# JSP editor for eclipse, does it exist?

Tags: eclipse, jsp

I noticed that my Eclipse does not include JSP Editor. Does standard JSP editor exist for Eclipse and if so, where can one download it from?

[image]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The [JavaEE version of Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/moreinfo/jee.php) has full JSP support.  The standard java development version doesn't.

Alternatively, you should be able to install the [WebTools plugin(s)](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/) into an existing Eclipse, that should give you JSP support also.

Comment: After switching to the JavaEE version I also needed to right-click on a .jsp file and choose Open With > JSP Editor.  Until I did that they were still opening with the Text editor.

Comment: You can make it as default editor like this: in Eclipse go to Window -> Preferences -> General -> Editors -> File Associations, select *.jsp and make web page editor as default editor.

Comment: @blackwolf thanks so much, that is that I need!!

Answer (score 6):

I had this same problem!

I resolved it by switching my eclipse perspective to JAVA EE perspective.

Answer (score 3):

Go to help -> Install New Software and install webtool.

And for whomever that still not seeing the editor, set JSP editor to be the default editor for JSP files in this way

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Having the same problem, I researched this and I found many solutions.  After installing the Web Tool PLug-Ins, I was able to get the .jsp editor to work.  Its important to know that you must close your .jsp files then reopen it, or you may be convinced that the solution didn't work.  You can confirm that the Web Tool Install worked if you go to the following:

Window -> Preferences
In the list of options, you will see General.  Expand that menu.
Expand the "Editors" menu
Click on the option "File Assocations"
There will be a "file type" (I'm using Keleper) with a list of different file types.
In this list, select .jsp.
In this list you should see a list of editors. Select JSP editor.  Then click OK.

This is something I discovered when trying to get mine to work.

Comment: This doesn't worked for me. The intellisense for .jsp files is not working

Answer (score 0):

Go To Preference->General->Editors->File Associations 
Check editor for *.jsp type.
If it's not present, add one.
If it's Class file viewer, then remove it.
Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

To install from within IDE for newer Eclipse clients:

Help->Eclipse Marketplace

Search for "Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools".  Install.